# My life calculater project

Tags: python, projects-and-solutions

I'm currently working on a life calculator that i have programmed in python. I need ideas of what to add to it and examples on how to add it and also how do i add a end control so i can just input end and the program stops. I'm trying to make this better because i plan to take it to a technology fair im going to. Here is my code.

```
print("The Life Calculator")


name = input("What is you're name? ") 
age = int(input("age:  "))


months = age * 12                 #This equals to how many months you have been alive.


days = age * 365                  #This equals to how many days you have been alive.


hours = age * 8765.81             #This equals to how many hours you have been alive.


minutes = age * 31556926          #This equals to how many minutes you have been alive.


seconds = age * 3.156e+7          #This equals to how many seconds you have been alive.


miliseconds = age * 3.15569e10    #This equals to how many miliseconds you have been alive.


microseconds = age * 3.156e+13    #This equals to how many microseconds you have been alive.


nanoseconds = age * 3.156e+16     #This equals to how many nanoseconds you have been alive.





print("This is how many months you have been alive.")               
print (months)        #This shows how many months you have been alive.

print("This is how many days you have been alive.")
print (days)         #This shows how many months you have been alive.

print("This is how many hours you have been alive.")
print (hours)         #This shows how many hours you have been alive.

print("This is how many minutes you have been alive.")
print (minutes)       #This shows how many minutes you have been alive.

print("This is how many seconds you have been alive.")
print (seconds)       #This shows how many seconds you have been alive.

print("This is how many miliseconds you have been alive.")
print (miliseconds)   #This shows how many miliseconds you have been alive.

print("This is how many microseconds you have been alive.")
print (microseconds)  #This shows how many microseconds you have been alive.

print("This is how many nanoseconds you have been alive.")
print (nanoseconds)   #This shows how many nanoseconds you have been alive.

lastline = ("this is how long you have been alive, so what are you going to do with the rest of your life?")

print (name)

print (lastline)
```

Comment: Austin, you should fix your indent. Also it's just a simple math calculating program. What is the desired thing?

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to take the user's age in years as an integer and then claim to report an exact number of minutes they've been alive.

Comment: This code works fine there isn't anything wrong with it and im just asking if maybe i should add things to the program to make it better if you get what i mean,. and i also wanted to now how i could make it to were i could in the program by typing end. I have tried several different ways to do it but none of them seem to work the way i wont them to are they just don't work period

Comment: should i change it to like this is the estimation of how long you have been alive?

Comment: @AustinJames What you mean about `end`? You want to stop running your program when user types `end`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a spiffed-up version.

I took a lot of the repetitive statements and converted them to data:

```
from collections import namedtuple

TimeUnit = namedtuple("TimeUnit", ["name", "per_year"])

units = [
    TimeUnit("decade",            0.1 ),
    TimeUnit("month",            12.0 ),
    TimeUnit("fortnight",        26.09),
    TimeUnit("day",             365.25),
    TimeUnit("hour",           8765.81),
    TimeUnit("minute",        31556926),
    TimeUnit("second",        3.156e+7),
    TimeUnit("millisecond", 3.15569e10)
]

def get_float(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def main():
    print("The Life Calculator")

    name = input("What is your name? ") 
    years = get_float("What is your age? ")

    print("You have been alive for:")
    for unit in units:
        print("  {} {}s".format(years * unit.per_year, unit.name))
    print("what are you going to do with the rest of your life, {}?".format(name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If the OP wants to make his program better, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is running once, not multiple times so actually you don't have to ask to user for `end`. However, if you want to run your program until user types `end`, you have to put that codes in a `while` loop.

If you want to stop running your program when user types `end`, just add this line to your program;

```
while True:

    #your codes here
    #end of your codes add this line
    ask=input("Want to end it?")
    if ask.lower()=="end":
        break
```

Using `lower()` so even user types `END or eND or EnD etc.` it will be ok.

Comment: ok the code you gave me is working in the python shell but when I try to use it in the console it only lets me enter my name and then it closes.

Comment: @AustinJames If it's closes in console then something wrong in your codes. There must be an error message in console.

Comment: Ok but if there is a error thin why does it not tell me when i run it in the IDLE

Comment: @AustinJames  Because Console and IDLE not same. A thing may throw an error in console but it may be ok in IDLE.

Comment: Ok i didn't know that thanks for telling me. do you know of anyway i could figure out what the error is. and i have ran this in console before and it worked before but that was before i changed to 3.4.2. And thanks guys for the help, sorry for being a pain.

Comment: Try to print screen when you open it on console. Press print-screen quickly try to catch the console screen then you can tell me what is the error.

Comment: it does not wait long enough it just quits but even if i can't get it to run n console is not a big deal i was just going to do it to make it look kinda better.